# Properly terminate flask web app running in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, kill-process

How to properly terminate a flask web application that was launched in a separate thread? I found an incomplete [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264826/start-a-flask-application-in-separate-thread?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) that is not clear on how to do it. The script below starts a thread which in turn starts a flask application. When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, something is not being terminated and the script never stops. It would be nice to add the code after `except KeyboardInterrupt:` that terminates the `app` and the `thread_webAPP()` properly. I know how to terminate a thread, but first I need to terminate the app:

```
def thread_webAPP():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    def nothing():
        return "Hello World!"

    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
    # hope that after app.run() is terminated, it returns here, so this thread could exit


t_webApp = threading.Thread(name='Web App', target=thread_webAPP)
t_webApp.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("exiting")
    # Here I need to kill the app.run() along with the thread_webAPP
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dont `join` child thread. Use `setDaemon` instead:

```
from flask import Flask
import time
import threading


def thread_webAPP():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    def nothing():
        return "Hello World!"

    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)


t_webApp = threading.Thread(name='Web App', target=thread_webAPP)
t_webApp.setDaemon(True)
t_webApp.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("exiting")
    exit(0)
```

`daemon` for a child thread means that the main thread won't wait till this daemon child thread is finished its job if you're trying to stop the main thread. In this case all child threads will be joined automatically and the main thread will be successfully stopped immediately.

More info is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

Comment: Have not tried yet your suggestion - will let you know. I am surprised that no one commented on anything.

Comment: @Nazar sure :) pls consider my post as an answer then

Comment: exit(0) does not help. Terminal does not return. Looks like the app is still running.

Comment: Did you launch code I provided? exit(0) works just fine. Here is the output I get after Cntrl+C: https://pastebin.com/TRp3KXKP

Comment: You were right. After I added `t_webApp.setDaemon(True)`, it exited properly. I hope it does not leave any "ghost" processes behind. Thank you.

Comment: I'm concerned about if an explicit call to `stop` on the flask thread is needed to ensure that the thread ends in a clean manner