# Can not stop python flask thread upon system exit

Tags: flask, ngrok

I have exhausted searching the web for this task --> [Properly terminate flask web app running in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469978/properly-terminate-flask-web-app-running-in-a-thread)

I have even written a smaller version of my original code but cant seem to terminate flask thread,

when I have this code, all threads start then gracefully exit:

```
def thrdCode1(arg):
    for i in range(arg):
        print("running")
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ngrokSetup()
    thrdH = Thread(target=thrdCode1, args=(2,))
    thrdH.deman = True
    thrdH.start()
    print("1---")
    thrdH.join()
    print("thread finished...exiting")
```

However when thread is with flask app.run, my thread starts but it never exits I even tried exit(-1)

```
def thrdCode2(arg):
    app.secret_key = 'my Top Secret'
    app.run(use_reloader=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ngrokSetup()
    thrdH = Thread(target=thrdCode1, args=(2,))
    thrdH.deman = True
    thrdH.start()
    print("1---")
    thrdH.join()
    print("thread finished...exiting")
```

I even tried exit(-1) at end

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to fix this issue by sending a shutdown req. to flask